# What type of algorithms are faster with a quantum computer?

Tags: algorithms, quantum-computing

I am a beginning CS student and I am learning algorithms. I heard that even with quantum computers, that general sorting algorithms can never have better than $n\log n$ time. However, I also know that factoring algorithms would be a lot faster. In general terms what kind of algorithms would become substantially faster with quantum computers?

Comment: I suggest you rephrase your question. You are really asking which problems can be solved faster with quantum computers.

Comment: Scott Aaronson (the quantum computing guru) has (two versions of a) talk about this subject exactly, titled *When exactly do quantum computers provide a speedup?". You can find it (or rather, them) here: http://scottaaronson.com/talks/.

Comment: As far as I know, *none*. We need new algorithms. (cf Yuval's first comment.)

Comment: it is not actually proven that factoring is faster, only conjectured, etc., its an open question P ?= BQP etc

Comment: Closely related: [Why and how is a quantum computer faster than a regular computer?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/21727/why-and-how-is-a-quantum-computer-faster-than-a-regular-computer)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- Shor's algorithm which puts FACTORING in BQP (*bounded error quantum polynomial-time*, effectively the quantum equivalent of P) also can be used to solve the [DISCRETE LOGARITHM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) problem, where we want to find an integer $k$ such that $a^{k} = b$ where $a$ and $b$ are given, in (quantum) polynomial time. The DISCRETE LOGARITHM problem has the same status as the FACTORING problem in that we don't know whether they are polynomial-time solvable, so this might not be a speed up.
- [Grover's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm) gives a quadratic speed up in searching unsorted lists (which can be used as a speed up for a lot of algorithms).
- Simulating quantum systems is also in BQP, but exponentially slower on a classical TM.
- Solving [Pell's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation) (not really one equation) is in BQP, another exponentially speed-up.
- There's also a number of other, more obscure, problems that are in BQP, but appear not to be in P. [Wocjan and Zhang](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0606179) give a good starting point to dig them up.