# How correct was Justin Trudeau's explanation of Quantum Computing?

Tags: quantum-computing

Recently, Canada's Prime Minister - Justin Trudeau - [gave an impromptu explanation of Quantum Computing](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2016-04-17/justin-trudeau-explains-quantum-computing/7332904), much to the crowd's astonishment. I certainly thought that I "got" Quantum Computing a little bit more, even though it was a simplified explanation.

Here's the [YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eak_ogYMprk) to the actual press conference.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eak_ogYMprk

However, [some are claiming](https://www.washingtonpost.com/posteverything/wp/2016/04/18/actually-justin-trudeau-doesnt-get-quantum-computing/) that we shouldn't jump for joy at his explanation.

I'm wondering, as someone who doesn't exactly understand Quantum Computing, **how accurate was Justin Trudeau's explanation of Quantum Computing?**

Comment: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/32539 ​ ​

Comment: What is your proposed unit of measurement for "accurate"?

Comment: @RickyDemer Interesting, didn't think to look there first.

Comment: [Accuracy vs precision](http://cdn.antarcticglaciers.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/precision_accuracy.png) shows that with arbitrary precision - yes, he was accurate, the topic of his speech matches the topic given.

Comment: @Mooz : ​ I also wouldn't have thought to look there, but had previously gone to that after seeing it on Hot Network Questions. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Related: [Why and how is a quantum computer faster than a regular computer?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/21727/49817)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Trudeau's explanation wasn't wrong, but it also wasn't very informative.

Scott Aaronson, a well-known quantum computational complexity theorist, made [a blog post discussing it](http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=2694):

> What marks does Trudeau get for this? [...] Trudeau doesn’t really assert much here: basically, he just says that normal computers work using 1’s and 0’s, and that quantum computers are more complicated than that in some hard-to-explain way. [...]
>
> [...] I’d grade Trudeau’s explanation as substantially more accurate than what you’d get from a typical popular article. [...] clearly suggests that he knows it’s more subtle than just “0 and 1 at the same time,” and he also knows that he doesn’t really get it and that the journalists in the audience don’t either. [...]
>
> [Grade: **B+**].

There's a lot of discussion in the comments of that post.